# Multidimensional array push

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

How can I do something like this?

"type" = some string

```
ShowMarkers('vehicles');
ShowMarkers('houses');

HideMarkers('vehicles');

var my_array = [];
function ShowMarkers(type)
{
    //code
    var gmm = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        //code
    });
    my_array[type].push(gmm);
    //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined 
}

function HideMarkers(type)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < my_array[type].length; i++)
    {
        my_array[type][i].setMap(null); //Hide the markers
    }
    my_array[type] = []; //Empty the array of `type`
}
```

I basically got  3 different map icons that I want users to be able to remove individually

Comment: How do you declare and initialize `my_array`? And what is the value of `type`?

Comment: What's the `my_array[type] = [];` supposed to do and/or why does it come in the end?

Comment: I declare it as:
`var my_array = [];`
....

This is supposed to empty the array
`my_array[type] = [];`
.....
type is "vehicles", "houses" or "other"

Comment: If it's really like that it should works. Edit and put the complete code please.

Comment: Sorry for beaing unclear. I've updated the main post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th problem is that `my_array[type]` is undefined if you call `ShowMarkers` before `HideMarkers`.

Change your function to this:

```js
function ShowMarkers(type)
{
    //code
    var gmm = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        //code
    });
    if (!(my_array[type] instanceof Array)) {
        my_array[type] = [];
    }
    my_array[type].push(gmm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `my_array[type] = [];` to the top, and make sure `type` has a value of a string or number